# find out percentage of duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data:

```
    id     date     A   Area  Price  Hol
0   1   2019-01-01  No  80    200    No
1   2   2019-01-02  Yes 100   300    Yes
2   3   2019-01-03  Yes 100   300    Yes
3   4   2019-01-04  No  50    100    No
4   5   2019-01-05  No  20    50     No
5   1   2019-01-01  No  80    200    No
```

I want to find out duplicates (for the same id).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1], 'date': ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04',
                                                     '2019-01-05', '2019-01-01'],
                   'A': ['No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No'],
                   'Area': [80, 100, 100, 50, 20, 80], 'Price': [200, 300, 300, 100, 50, 200],
                   'Hol': ['No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 7))

df.groupby(['A', 'Area', 'Price', 'Hol'])['id'].value_counts().plot(ax=ax)
```

I can see that I have one duplicate (for id 1 , all the entries are the same)

Now, I want to find out what percentage those duplicates represent in the whole dataset.

I can't find a way to express this, since I am already using `value_counts()` in order to find the duplicates and I can't do something like:

`df.groupby(['A', 'Area', 'Price', 'Hol'])['id'].value_counts().size()`

`percentage = (test / test.groupby(level=0).sum()) * 100`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
percentage = df.duplicated(keep=False).value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
print (percentage)
False    66.666667
True     33.333333
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

Is `duplicated` what you need ?

```
df.duplicated(keep=False).mean()
Out[107]: 0.3333333333333333
```